# Arduino sending serial data to Hololens 2(Unity) via USB C

Tags: c#, uwp, arduino, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

im trying to find my Arduino on my hololens with the `Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceWatcher.Added` event but it doesnt come up, on my pc the uwp console app works and i can read the arduino serial data.

`DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector())` also does not work as it only returns the hololens itself. Looking specificly for the device using its VID an PID also returns device.Count == 0:

`string selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid(vid,pid); DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector, null);`

all these methods work and have been tested on pc, Hololens seems to not add the arduino to the DeviceInformation list. the weird thing is when you go to Setting/Devices on the hololens you can see the arduino even with name(Seeeduino nano in my case) but it gets disconnected and reconnected every other second.

also when you put this in the uwp Package.appxmanifest the unity app wont start on the hololens, but this has nothing to do with finding the device in the list only with creating the SerialDevice.

```
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication"/>
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to read the serial data from arduino using usb c connected to the hololens?

Comment: The [Serial Arduino sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SerialArduino) in Windows-universal-samples shows how to communicate with an Arduino device on UWP apps. Could you deploy this sample first to check whether `SerialCommunication` work fine on HoloLens, so that we can narrow it down your own code part?

Comment: Thank you for your response i greatly appreciate it! i will get back to you when i have tested the sample, i don't have too much hope, since i already had it worken inside a uwp app that i ran on my pc. the functions i mentioned all returned the Arduino DeviceInformation but on the HoloLens it does not seem to return the DeviceInformation, maybe microsoft blocked it or the HoloLens does not have the drivers for serial communication.

Comment: ok so i just tested the arduino sample. i first had to fix it using this tut: [link](https://schrenk.hu/2016/12/16/FixSerialArduino/). the sample works on my pc and i can see my arduino and connect with it. But when deployed to my HoloLens it does not show up. I think this confirms that its just not possible to communicate over USB C.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is recommended you try to communicate with Arduino over Network such as Bluetooth or Wi-Fi. Besides, you can provide more information about your request and submit a feature request via feedback hub on new feature request to be considered in future releases of HoloLens OS and devices. If it's a hot impacted feature, it will be possible to be given priority to jump in the development schedule.

For how to post feedback request, you can follow this doc: [Send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332).